# Artinian Tor modules (Reference request)

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

I am looking for a *reference* for the following basic fact:

> Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, let $M$ be an artinian $R$-module, let $N$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, and let $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, $Tor_i^R(M,N)$ is artinian.

(I know that it is easy to prove. I guess nevertheless that this is written down somewhere in the standard literature about homological algebra, and I would like to know where.)

*Remark 1:* The above conclusion also holds if $R$ is coherent, $M$ is artinian, and $N$ is of finite presentation. A reference for this generalisation would also be fine.

*Remark 2:* Leamer proves in his PhD Thesis (2010) a generalisation to the case where $R$ is noetherian, $M$ is artinian, and $N$ is minimax. But I guess there must be an earlier reference for the less general case.

Comment: I doubt that there is a precise reference. As you point out, this is a straightforward consequence of the definitions; if I had to use it, I'd just say that, I wouldn't bother to write a lemma.

Comment: Ok, it seems there is no such reference. Thanks, @abx, for your suggestion, to which I will probably adhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from the slightly more general Lemma 2.2 in M. Brodmann, S. Fumasoli, R. Tajarod, *Local cohomology over homogeneous rings with one-dimensional local base ring,* Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 131 (2003), 2977-2985, which considers additionally a change of rings.